# Why updating of InplaceSearchEnabled of the listview webpart does not reflect on the page?

Tags: 2013, powershell, xslt-list-view-web-part

We have a script that generates pages that contains list view web part. The script sets the `InplaceSearchEnabled` of the web part true, but when we check the pages, the search box does not appear. I have to update the web part through browser to make the searchbox visible.

Below is the portion of the script we use.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb $path
$pageType = "Test"
$pageName = "PageName"

try {
    $page = $web.GetFile("pages/" + $pageType + "/" + $pageName + ".aspx")
    if (!$page.Exists)
    {
        $pubWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)
        $pageLayout = $pubWeb.GetAvailablePageLayouts() | Where { $_.Name -eq "SamplePageLayout.aspx" }
        if ($pageLayout)
        {
            $folder = $web.GetFolder("Pages/"+$pageType)
            $page = $pubWeb.AddPublishingPage($pageName + ".aspx", $pageLayout, $folder)

            $webPartManager = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($page.Url, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)


            $listViewWebPart = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart
            # set up list view webpart . . .
            $listViewWebPart.InplaceSearchEnabled = $true

            $webPartManager.AddWebPart($listViewWebPart, "some guid number", 0)
            $page.CheckIn("")
            $page.ListItem.File.Publish("")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to also set the `ClientRender`property to `$true`?

Comment: @RobertLindgren , sorry, setting `ClientRender` true didn't worked.

Comment: OK, also setting `ServerRender=$false`?

Comment: @RobertLindgren, sorry, didn't also work. I was thinking of just copying an existing working page and updated the new copied page.

Comment: I've seen around the web that others also seem to have this problem when not using a plain webpart page. Not that that makes it any better ;)

Comment: Hi, Have you found a solution?

Comment: Also wondering if you have found a solution for this. Have exactly the same issue. Wonder why it works when I change it through browser. Which methods are used when changing the settings by browser? Issues like this is why I love SharePoint soooo much :-)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it using JavaScript (actually, it's a workaround). It won't set the flag itself to true but will 'emulate' it. Here is a copy-paste-able code. If you want some explanations, please use the link: [InplaceSearchEnabled doesn't work when set programmatically in XsltListViewWebPart](http://tricky-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2016/07/inplacesearchenabled-doesnt-work-when.html)

```
/// we need to wait until clienttemplates.js is loaded
SP.SOD.executeFunc('clienttemplates.js', 'SPClientTemplates', function () {
    // code that will be run before rendering the script. It'a good time to configure everything for search input
    function onPreRender(ctx) {
        if (!window.g_listSearchBoxInfo)
            window.g_listSearchBoxInfo = [];
        var hasSearch = false;
        // if the searci is configured for this web part we won't want to add it twice
        for (var i = 0, len = window.g_listSearchBoxInfo.length; i &lt; len; i++) {
            if (window.g_listSearchBoxInfo[i].wpq === ctx.wpq) {
                hasSearch = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!hasSearch) {
            // the structure of the object was got during debugging session
            window.g_listSearchBoxInfo.push({
                fullSearchSiteUrl: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,
                loadInProgress: false,
                searchBoxConstructor: null,
                sodFunc: null,
                sodKey: null,
                wpq: ctx.wpq
            });

            // setting InplaceSearchEnabled in ListSchema
            ctx.ListSchema.InplaceSearchEnabled = true;
        }
     }

    // registering CSR template override
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.OnPreRender = onPreRender;

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

    // adding scripts (with condition if there were previously added or not)
    var searchScript = jQuery('script[src*="listsearchboxbootstrap.js"]');
    if (!searchScript.length) {
        RegisterSod('clientrenderer.js', '/_layouts/15/clientrenderer.js');
        RegisterSod('srch.resources.resx', '/_layouts/15/ScriptResx.ashx?culture=en-us&amp;name=Srch.Resources');
        RegisterSod('search.clientcontrols.js', '/_layouts/15/search.clientcontrols.js')
        RegisterSodDep('search.clientcontrols.js', 'clientrenderer.js');
        RegisterSodDep('search.clientcontrols.js', 'srch.resources.resx');
        RegisterSod('profilebrowserscriptres.resx', '/_layouts/15/ScriptResx.ashx?culture=en-us&amp;name=ProfileBrowserScriptRes');
        RegisterSod('sp.ui.listsearchbox.js', '/_layouts/15/sp.ui.listsearchbox.js');
        RegisterSodDep('sp.ui.listsearchbox.js', 'search.clientcontrols.js');
        RegisterSodDep('sp.ui.listsearchbox.js', 'profilebrowserscriptres.resx');

        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = '/_layouts/15/sp.ui.listsearchboxbootstrap.js';
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi AJIXuMuK in case links break in the future it is best practice to least list the main/general steps on how to implement the answer (for example the logic of the code while the link show how to implement the code).

Comment: updated to provide to code with some comments